# BufferedWriter only saving last input in text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am currently creating a simple AI (Simsimi) program. I teach the program what it should reply to my phrases so that when I "talk" to it, it will reply if what I'm saying are already "taught" to the program. However, I also need to save the list of replies the program have already learned and so far only the last input is being saved. What do I mean? Let's say the program has been taught to reply the phrases `Hello`, `Good morning`, and `Have a good day!`.

I need to save all those three in a text file called `response.txt`. However, given that the order of inputs are the same, I am only able to save `Have a good day!` into the file. Here's my code:

```
 System.out.println("\nWhat should I reply to that?\n"); 
 answer = simsimiInput.nextLine(); 
 try {  
      writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("response.txt"));
      writer.write(answer);
      writer.close();

 } catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What happens if you assign a hardcoded value to `answer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting the file every time you call the block within `try`.

You need to tell `FileWriter` to append to file.

```
new FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append);
```

i.e.

```
new FileWriter("response.txt", true);
```